# while playing gif animation some times getting nullpointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-animation, animated-gif

I'm playing `gif animation` in my app. Its working good, but if I'm playing so many times same `animation`, its throw `nullpointer exception` in movie object.

any suggestion about this problem. below is my code

**SampleView.class:**

```
 class SampleView extends View {
           java.io.InputStream is;


            private Movie mMovie;
            private long mMovieStart;

            private  byte[] streamToBytes(InputStream is) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                try {
                    while ((len = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                        os.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                }
                return os.toByteArray();
            }

            public SampleView(Context context) {
                super(context);



                    if(is==null)
                    {

                try {
                    is =context.getAssets().open("a.gif");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    }


                    mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);

            }

            public SampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
                super(context,attrs);

                    if(is==null)
                    {

                try {
                    is =context.getAssets().open("a.gif");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    }

                mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
            }
            public SampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
                super(context,attrs,defStyle);

                    if(is==null)
                    {

                try {
                    is =context.getAssets().open("a.gif");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    }

                    mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
            }


            @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

                long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                if (mMovieStart == 0) {   // first time
                    mMovieStart = now;
                }
                if (mMovie != null) {
                    int dur = mMovie.duration();
                    if (dur == 0) {
                        dur = 1000;
                    }
                    int relTime = (int)((now - mMovieStart) % dur);
                    mMovie.setTime(relTime);
                    mMovie.draw(canvas, getWidth() - mMovie.width(),
                                getHeight() - mMovie.height());
                    invalidate();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: O radha! post your error log too.

Comment: Whats with all these people saying "I get an exception" but then either not looking at the exception, or not posting any details when asking for help?

Comment: ok. mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is); this line i am getting nullpointer exception

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public class GIFDemo extends GraphicsActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new GIFView(this));
}

private static class GIFView extends View {

    Movie movie;
    InputStream is = null;
    long moviestart;
    long moviestart1;

    public GIFView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        is = context.getResources()
                .openRawResource(R.drawable.animated_gif);

        movie = Movie.decodeStream(is);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(0xFFCCCCCC);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        System.out.println("now=" + now);
        if (moviestart == 0) { // first time
            moviestart = now;

        }

        System.out.println("\tmoviestart=" + moviestart);
        int relTime = (int) ((now - moviestart) % movie.duration());
        // int relTime1 = (int) ((now - moviestart1) % movie1.duration());
        System.out.println("time=" + relTime + "\treltime="
                + movie.duration());
        movie.setTime(relTime);
        // movie1.setTime(relTime1);
        movie.draw(canvas, 10, 10);
        // movie1.draw(canvas, 10, 100);
        this.invalidate();
    }
}
}
```

Add this GraphicsActivity calss.

```
  class GraphicsActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View view) {

    super.setContentView(view);
}
}
```

Comment: sory,i tried using ur code.but now also i am getting exception.my log result is

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 11:52:09.737: E/AndroidRuntime(28198):  at android.graphics.Movie.decodeStream(Native Method)
02-27 11:52:09.737: E/AndroidRuntime(28198):  at com.example.kidsletters1.A$SampleView.<init>(A.java:1081)
02-27 11:52:09.737: E/AndroidRuntime(28198):  at com.example.kidsletters1.A.onCreate(A.java:111)

Comment: @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.alh);
      sampleview=new SampleView(this);
     lp6 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            sampleview.setLayoutParams(lp6);
           lp6.setMargins(0,topsampl , 0, 0);

Comment: i want xml file also so i gave like this,using custom class sample view

Comment: in same GraphicsActivity  class i want display some xml stuff also

Comment: sory,i didnt get u.i want to play gif file,webview means we can display either url,html file.i dont know how to play gif file using webview

Comment: ok create index.html in your assets . write this code    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body bgcolor="#333333">
       <table width="100%" height="100%">
               <tr>
                       <td align="center" valign="center"><img
                               src="file:///android_asset/gif/placement_tutorial.gif"></td>
               </tr>
       </table>
</body>
</html>

Comment: and then create gif folder inside folder and then paste your gif image into that folder

Comment: and then use webview. webTutorial = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webTutorial);
             

               webTutorial.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
               webTutorial.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
               webTutorial.setInitialScale(0);

               webTutorial.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

Comment: to avoid webview scroll able use this code webTutorial.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                               return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
                       }
               });

Comment: let me know any clarification. ask me

Comment: but i want draw functionality also

Comment: i want to display alphets in on draw and if i click any button i need to play gif animation like tracing that alhabets